# Open CV Build getting failed for v4.6.0

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, camera

This is the build gradle for opencv 4.6.0
`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

```
def openCVersionName = "4.6.0"
def openCVersionCode = ((4 * 100 + 6) * 100 + 0) * 10 + 0

println "OpenCV: " +openCVersionName + " " + 
project.buildscript.sourceFile

android {
    namespace 'org.opencv'
    compileSdkVersion 33

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 33

    versionCode openCVersionCode
    versionName openCVersionName

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
            targets "opencv_jni_shared"
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        packagingOptions {
            doNotStrip '**/*.so'  // controlled by OpenCV CMake scripts
        }
    }
    release {
        packagingOptions {
            doNotStrip '**/*.so'  // controlled by OpenCV CMake scripts
        }
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['native/libs']
        java.srcDirs = ['java/src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['java/src']
        res.srcDirs = ['java/res']
        manifest.srcFile 'java/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path (project.projectDir.toString() + '/libcxx_helper/CMakeLists.txt')
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

}`

Getting error while building error: package OpenCVEngineInterface does not exist
i am unable to import that
OpenCVEngineInterface file exist in the package[The image were the file exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDmiU.png)

Using
Android Studio Flamingo
Compile and traget sdk version 33

Tried opencv version 4.8.0, 3.4.1 and more all are getting the same issue

Unable to find OpenCVEngineInterface.java